# Is there any difference using 'return' after Discord.js function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord.js, commando

I am coding a Discord bot with a Commando framework and I was wondering if the usage of `return` keyword after last Discord.js or Commando function in the given function is needed to **end/finish** the command or is it not needed at all? I want to make sure that that particular command is finished. If it even makes sense.

```
const { Command } = require('discord.js-commando');

module.exports = class HelloCommand extends Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            name: 'Hello',
            aliases: [],
            group: 'general',
            memberName: 'hello',
            description: 'Displays the Hello message',
            guildOnly: true
        });
    }

    run(message) {
        return message.channel.send("Hello!");
    }
};
```

If it's needed, in which one of these ways should it be used? Does it matter at all?

```
run(message) {
    return message.channel.send("Hello!");
}
```

Or

```
run(message) {
    message.channel.send("Hello!");
    return;
}
```

Comment: Hey @K.DV, i believe it doens't make any change if you use `return message.channel.send("Hello!");` or `message.channel.send("Hello!"); return;` but in node i'm always using the first kind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one is pointless as all javascript functions automatically returns `undefined` whether you use `return` in the end of the function or not. I would suggest the usage of 1st one.

You can check if you need the `return` in the 1st one by doing this

```
run(message) {
        const response = message.channel.send("Hello!");
        console.log(response)
    }
```

If the console prints `undefined`, you don't have to use return at all.

Answer (score 0):

[If you are not sure you can always look for typings definition in github](https://github.com/discordjs/Commando/blob/master/typings/index.d.ts#L101)

```js
export class Command {

  public run(message: CommandoMessage, args: object | string | string[], fromPattern: 
    boolean, result?: ArgumentCollectorResult): Promise<Message | Message[] | null> | 
    null;
}
```

Well that means you can return either Promise or nothing.